# Find sets of terms of given sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

I want to find the  sets of the terms of the sequences $\left( n-2 \left[\frac{n}{2}\right]\right), \left( n-3 \left[\frac{n}{3}\right]\right) $ and more general, if $m$ is natural the set of the terms of $\left( n-m \left[\frac{n}{m}\right]\right)$.

We know that $\left( n-m \left[\frac{n}{m}\right]\right)$ is equal to the largest integer $k$ for which $k \leq \frac{n}{m}<k+1$.

But how can we find a general form for the terms of the given sequences and consequently the desired sets?

Comment: Have you tried just writing what $(n - 2 [n/2])$ equals for $n=1,2,3,4,\ldots$? If you just write things out, you might be able to find a pattern and then formalize your guess into a proof.

Comment: Note:  $[n/2]=n/2$ when $n$ is even and $(n-1)/2$ when $n$ is odd

Comment: $n-m\left[\frac nm\right]=n \mod m$

Comment: For $n=3k$ it holds that $\left[ \frac{n}{3}\right]=\frac{n}{3}$, for $n=3k+1$ it holds that $\left[ \frac{n}{3}\right]=\frac{n-1}{3}$ and for $n=3k+2$ it holds that $\left[ \frac{n}{3}\right]=\frac{n-2}{3}$, right?

So if $n=3k$ then $n-3 \left[ \frac{n}{3}\right]=0$, if $n=3k+1$ then $n-3 \left[ \frac{n}{3}\right]=1$ and for $n=3k+2$ it holds that $n-3 \left[ \frac{n}{3}\right]=2$, right?

Answer (score 0):

For natural number $m$ and integer $n$, $n-m \left[\frac{n}{m}\right] \equiv n \bmod m$. The sets are those of the integers modulo $m$, $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.